# Tailwindcss and Flowbite - flowbite.min.js file not found (404) in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13, flowbite

I want to use only `flowbite` package with tailwind in my nextjs application. I configure everything correctly. But adding `flowbite.min.js` script throws me error -

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I add the script in my `_app.js` file as nextjs documentation suggested. Here is my `_app.js` file

```
import Script from 'next/script'
import '~/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src='../node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js' />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

In flowbite [documentation](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/) at number 4 they suggest to add this script end of the body tag

```
<script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

Since I'm using nextjs, I add this script in my `_app.js` file. I try with cdn and it works. Probably I'm adding path wrongly. What should be the path for `flowbite.min.js` script?

In nextjs I don't want to use `flowbite-react`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using flowbites cdn, as sometimes your node_modules isn’t in the public folder.

CDN url: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.4/flowbite.min.js

Comment: Yeah, I'm using cdn for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [nextjs specific setup guide in flowbite docs](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/next-js/#install-flowbite-react) you should directly use flowbite components from the `flowbite-react` package.

1. install `flowbite-react`

```bash
npm install flowbite flowbite-react --save
```

2. Require Flowbite as a plugin inside your tailwind.config.js file:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@types/tailwindcss/tailwind-config').TailwindConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    // ...
    "./node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.js",
  ],
  plugins: [
    require("flowbite/plugin")
  ],
  // ...
};
```

So you can use Flowbite components like this:

```js
import { Alert } from "flowbite-react";

export default function MyPage() {
  return <Alert color="info">Alert!</Alert>;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I don't want to use flowbite-react.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to init it manually. I am using Next.js 13

```
'use client';

import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';
import { memo } from 'react';

/**
 * FlowbiteScript Component
 *
 * This component initializes the Flowbite functionality using the `initFlowbite` function.
 * It is memoized for performance optimization.
 *
 * @component
 * @return {React.Fragment} An empty fragment, as this component doesn't render visible content.
 *
 * @example
 * // Import the component
 * import FlowbiteScript from './FlowbiteScript';
 *
 * // Use the component in your JSX
 * <FlowbiteScript />
 */
const FlowbiteScript = () => {
   // Initialize Flowbite functionality
   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      initFlowbite();
   }

  // Return an empty fragment
  return <></>;
};

// Memoize the component for performance optimization
export default memo(FlowbiteScript);
```

Then I imported this component to the main layout.tsx and added in the body.

```
<FlowbiteScript />
```